# Subwords of the Thue-Morse Sequence

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

In addition to [Complexity of Thue-Morse Sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1821082/complexity-of-thue-morse-sequence), I have the following question:

Has anyone found a characterization for subwords of Thue–Morse sequence? I.e., for a given binary word, can I (easily for some definition of easy) decide whether it is a subword of the Thue–Morse sequence or not?
Any references (in addition to Brlek and de Luca–Varricchio) are very welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Thue-Morse sequence can be generated by repeatedly applying the replacement rule $(0 \to 01), (1 \to 10)$. To check if a word $w$ is a subword of the Thue-Morse sequence, we can apply this rule in reverse: try to "undo" the replacement rule, replacing $01$ by $0$ and $10$ by $1$. This gives us a new word half the length of $w$, and repeat until we're at a short word we know the answer to.

That's the high-level idea; here are the details.

If $w$ appears in the Thue-Morse sequence, it does not have to appear at an even position. For example, suppose we want to know if $001100$ appears in the Thue-Morse sequence:

- Naively, we might break this up into blocks as $[00][11][00]$ and then fail, because we can only replace $[01]$ by $0$ and $[10]$ by $1$; $[00]$ and $[11]$ are never the outputs of the replacement rule.
- But we can also break this up into blocks as $[.0][01][10][0.]$; in this case, the values replaced by $.$ must be $[10][01][10][01]$, and undoing the replacement rule gives us $1010$.

So which one should we do? We try both! If $w$ contains $00$ or $11$ as a subword, then those two symbols must be in separate blocks, so there's at most one way to continue. If $w$ does not contain $00$ or $11$ as a subword, then the $0$'s and $1$'s must alternate; such a $w$ is not contained in the Thue-Morse sequence when $|w| \ge 5$.

This is an $O(|w|)$ algorithm; in linear time, we can either undo the replacement rule or realize that we cannot do it, and then we get a word of length about $\frac12|w|$ to recurse on.

### An example which is a subword

Suppose we want to know if `0010110100101100110100110010` appears in the Thue-Morse sequence.

1. Separating it into `00 10 11 01 00 10 11 00 11 01 00 11 00 10` does not work; there are `00`'s and `11`'s. So we separate it as `.0 01 01 10 10 01 01 10 01 10 10 01 10 01 0.` and undo the replacement rule to get `100110010110100`.
2. Separating this into `10 01 10 01 01 10 10 0.` works (but separating it into `.1 00 11 00 10 11 01 00` would not). We undo the replacement rule to get `10100110`.
3. Separating this into `10 10 01 10` works (but separating it into `.1 01 00 11 0.` would not). We undo the replacement rule to get `1101`.
4. Separating this into `11 01` does not work, so we separate it into `.1 10 1.`. We undo the replacement rule to get `011`.
5. All words of length $3$ except for `000` and `111` occur in the Thue-Morse sequence; therefore, so does our original word. (We could compute all the words of some longer lengths in advance, and stop earlier.)

### An example which is not a subword

Suppose we want to know if `10110011010011001011010010110100101` appears in the Thue-Morse sequence.

1. Separating it into `10 11 00 11 01 00 11 00 10 11 01 00 10 11 01 00 10 1.` does not work, so we separate it into `.1 01 10 01 10 10 01 10 01 01 10 10 01 01 10 10 01 01`. We undo the replacement rule to get `001011010011001100`.
2. Separating this into `00 10 11 01 00 11 00 11 00` does not work, so we separate it into `.0 01 01 10 10 01 10 01 10 0.`. We undo the replacement rule to get `1001101010`.
3. Separating this into `10 01 10 10 10` works (but separating it into `.1 00 11 01 01 0.` would not). We undo the replacement rule to get `10111`.
4. Now neither `10 11 1.` nor `.1 01 11` work: both contain a `11` block, which cannot be the result of the replacement rule. So this word does not appear in the Thue-Morse sequence; therefore, neither does our original word.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! Everything is much clearer now (:

Answer (score 5):

If you want an algorithm then here it is: the Prouhet-Morse-Thue sequence is given by the iteration of the map $1\mapsto 10, 0\mapsto 01$ starting with $1$. If you want to check if a word $w$ is a subword of the sequence, start with $1$ and iterate the map sufficient number of times. The sequence is uniformly recurrent (Morse), so "sufficient" is not large, at most $|w|$ in this case because every subword $U$ of length $2^{n}$ contains all subwords of length $n$. I am sure that the $2^n$ bound can be made polynomial and that the original problem is in $P$.

**Edit**. In fact by Theorem 8.2 in Morse, Marston; Hedlund, Gustav A. Symbolic Dynamics.
Amer. J. Math. 60 (1938), no. 4, 815–866
one can replace $2^n$ above by $10n$ and so the number of iterations needed is $O(\log n)$ and the time complexity of the problem is $O(n^2)$ (or $O(n)$ depending on the mode of computation).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Makes sense (:

Answer (score 3):

Here's a self-contained recursive algorithm that should run in $O(n)$ time on a word $w$ of length $n$.

0. If $n\leq 2$, accept. If $3\leq n\leq 4$, accept only if $w$ contains neither $000$ nor $111$ as a substring.
1. If $w$ contains $01010$ or $10101$ as a subword, reject.
2. Construct two words $w_1$ and $w_2$ from $w$ in the following way: If $n$ is even, let $w_1=w$ and let $w_2$ be $awb$, where $a,b\in\{0,1\}$ are chosen such that $a$ is different from the first character of $w$ and such that $b$ is different from the last character of $w$. If $n$ is odd, let $w_1=wb$ and $w_2=aw$, where $a$ and $b$ are chosen identically to the even case.
3. Check whether $w_1$ or $w_2$ is in $\{01,10\}^*$ (i.e. whether either is a string formed from concatenating some copies of either $01$ or $10$). If neither is, reject. If one of them, say $w_i$, is, then let $x$ to be the string formed by replacing each $01$ with $0$ and each $10$ with $1$. Note that $|x|\leq \frac{n}2+1$. (At most one of $w_1$ and $w_2$ is of this form, which I'll prove later.)
4. Run the algorithm on $x$. If it accepts, accept; if not, reject.

This algorithm spends $O(n)$ time to reduce the problem to one of input length at most $n/2+1$, and so its full runtime is $O(n)$.

---

We now show correctness. Let $\mathcal W$ be the set of all subwords of the Thue-Morse sequence. Firstly, it is easy to show that $\mathcal W$ contains every word of length at most $2$, that $\mathcal W$ does not contain $000$ or $111$ (as any $0$ in the Thue-Morse sequence must have a $1$ next to it, and any $1$ must have a $0$ next to it), and that it contains every $3$- and $4$-character word without a $000$ or $111$ subword. It may not contain $01010$ or $10101$, as these can only be generated using the rules $0\to 01$ and $1\to 10$ via starting with a $000$ or $111$ string. So, the algorithm behaves correctly on those words accepted or rejected in steps 0 and 1.

For steps 2 and 3, we see that, for a word $w$ to be in $\mathcal W$, it must occur at an even index or at an odd index in the Thue-Morse sequence. If it occurs at an even index, then it must begin with $01$ or $10$, then follow with a $01$ or $10$, et cetera; if $n$ is odd, a character distinct from its final character must follow it. Similarly, if $w$ occurs at an odd index, it must be preceded by a character distinct from its first character; after this, there must be a $01$ or $10$, et cetera. So, $w_1$ and $w_2$ as constructed represent the possible ways for $w$ to be contained in a minimal even-length even-index subword of the Thue-Morse sequence. If these are both in $\{01,10\}^*$, then $w$ must consist of alternating $0$s and $1$s, and so it would already have been dealt with in step 1. On the other hand, if some $w_i$ for $i\in\{1,2\}$ is formed by $01$s and $10$s, then the only way for $w$ to be in some iteration $k$ of the Thue-Morse sequence is for the word $x$ as constructed to be in iteration $k-1$ of the sequence. So, $w\in\mathcal W$ if and only if $x\in\mathcal  W$, and we can apply the algorithm recursively to get a correct result.

Comment: It looks like my answer is substantially the same as yours; my excuse is that your answer did not exist at the time I began writing. If you do not mind, I will keep my answer up; your answer proves some details that I did not, but my answer does have an example of the algorithm working.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Your answer is very nice, and I think it explains the intuition behind the algorithm much better! +1 to you

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for the detailed answers – to both of you!